# Node as reverse proxy throttles concurrency of java backend

Tags: java, node.js, concurrency, reverse-proxy

I have a java API backend and am currently using nodejs as a reverse proxy to it. For every request from browser node performs a set of normalisation operation on the request params and then forwards the request to the backend. I am afraid that node being single threaded and non concurrent will process requests sequentially effectively throttling the concurrency and eventually java concurrent processing is waste. Assuming I have a 4 node cluster for nodejs. My concurrency is limited to 4 irrespective of any number of concurrent requests before the reverse proxy. Is it correct?

Comment: No, that is not correct for properly-written Node code. We can't help you without seeing how your code is handling requests, but it appears that it's using synchronous I/O, which is strongly discouraged by the Node devs for exactly this reason, or some of the high-level abstractions that *look* async but still leave a lot of processing to the main thread. For instance -- you're probably not using this, it's just an example -- `fs.readFile` looks asynchronous, and reading each block is, but it processes each 8k (IIRC) block on the main thread before requesting the next.

Comment: Let's assume a small blocking operation of 10ms per request. 100 concurrent requests would mean an effective delay of 1 second before all requests reach the backend. In case there is absolutely no blocking operation 0 ms. Then yes all requests would reach the backend nearly the same time. So concurrency is retained only when close to no work is done per request?

Comment: 10ms is a ***long*** time to a production server. There's a huge difference between 10ms of blocking at the one end and "no work" at the other. What could the code be doing that blocks for 10ms?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder We are using Netflix falcor. To maintain JSON graph and caching on the browser. When the request comes from browser it is in falcor format. This request has to be transformed to a simple get request format, which can be understood by the java API layer.